# Is there a more modern/updated paper than Hurley's 2000 SSE?

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-evolution

I've implemented equations from Hurley's [2000 paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000MNRAS.315..543H) on Single Stellar Evolution (SSE) to model the stages of stellar evolution without having to use the full SSE code (or MESA for that matter).

Is there a more updated version of such a paper, where numerical formulae are given to model stages of stellar evolution? Has the knowledge base of the field of stellar evolution changed enough in the last 18 years to warrant an updated numerical formula recipe?

Here's the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0001295) of the paper.

Comment: My guess would be no because, as of this writing, there are 949 citations to that paper with a good chunk of them in this year.  You could always email the author(s) to discuss it.  Perhaps your effort could lead to an update.

Comment: @Dave Thank you! If you put your comment into an answer and just link where you found those recent citations, I'll certainly accept it as the answer. It's also what I thought, but I figured I'd ask the community.

Comment: You're welcome, and I put it in answer form with links.  Best wishes on your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be no because, as of this writing, from the paper [link you provided](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000MNRAS.315..543H) you can see [there are 949 citations](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/basic_connect?qsearch=hurley%20single%20star%20evolution&version=1) to that paper with a good chunk of them in this year. You could always [contact the author(s)](http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/~jhurley/) to discuss it. Perhaps your effort could lead to an update.

Comment: The SOA/NASA ADS is quite nifty!